# Creating a properties file in Java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a config.properties file, in which I want to store all the key and values instead of hard coding them in the Java code.

However, I do not know how to create a properties file in eclipse.
I researched and found help on how to read a properties file.
I need help with how to create it.

Here are my specific questions:

1. Can a `config.properties` file be created in eclipse, and data be
   typed directly into it as though the config.properties is similar to
   text editor?
2. If it can be directly created, the can you please let me know the
   steps to create this properties file?
3. I am assuming that properties file can be created just like how java
   project, java class etc are created (by right clicking at package or
   project level). Is this correct assumption?
4. Or creating a properties file and adding data to it needs to be done
   by java coding?

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you've to read to read the data from properties file in your java program?

Comment: i want to create a properties file and then read it in the java program. I understood the steps to read the properties file. I do not know the correct steps to create the properties file in eclipse.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Create a new file from file menu Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
2. In place of file name write  *config.properties* then click finish

Then you can add properties your property file like this

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=user
```

Example of loading properties

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

[image: By Edit]

[image: By Edit]

Comment: sadasidha, can you tell me the steps to the first two steps in your post. "Create a new file from file menu and name it config.properties

You can add properties like this in your property file"

Comment: @star1 I have simplified the tests and added images. Accept my  answer if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question in detail.