# How to set Java UCanAccess Driver Database URL to be accessible from cloud storage?

Tags: java, ucanaccess

I want to make it so that the driver manager can access my database from my OneDrive

When I set the `DriverManager` `URL` for my database, I have to hardcode a file path that only works for the computer that I am currently on (which in my case is a school computer).

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnection {
    //the driver and filepath to my database. 
    static String url = 
     "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/myName/OneDrive/elcipse/project/database.accdb 
       Projects/StockTrackerDB/StockTracker.accdb";
    static Connection con;
    static Statement stmt;
    public DatabaseConnection()
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        //code for database
    }
}
```

But if I want to work on my program on a different computer, say at home, I have to manually change the URL to match the file path on my home computer.

Is there a way to reference the file path so that its accessible from any computer that has access to my `OneDrive`?

I already tried using the **'.../file path/'** feature to reference the folder that the program is contained in but it returned with a driver not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a configuration file/property file in your application. If you don't have one you have to create a property file. And your application should read the file path from your property file. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010833/creating-a-properties-file-in-java-and-eclipse)  to find how can you create a property file for your project. If you have this facility you can modify it as per your need and avoid rework of code to correct the configuration.