# Disable a part of Java Program during JUnit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am testing my Java program with JUnit.
The program includes some JavaFX GUI interface and other logging code. However, during testing, I don't want these to be tested. Is there any way to switch the code between testing and development?

The description can be abstract, I'll use an example:

```
public class Helloworld {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static int greetingCnt = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Helloworld helloword = new Helloworld();
        helloword.greetWorld();
        helloword.greetWorld();
        helloword.greetWorld();
        System.out.println("Greating count: " + greetingCnt);
    }

    public void greetWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        ++greetingCnt;
        //some other computation...
    }

}
```

In this example, if I only want to test the correct number of greetingCnt but not want to have anything printed or any extra computation to be performed. But during actual program execution, there is no influence on the function of the program. May I know if there is any way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem seems to be in the way the code is structured, that is the printing and the increment are done in the same place. I'm not sure how this can be fixed in this example (maybe increment elsewhere and test *that* function?) but maybe it can be done in your actual case.

Comment: Hi Federico, thanks for the comments. What i am thinking is if there is anything equivalent to #define or preprocessor in Java, so that the program is able to change behavior a little bit according to different scenarios.

Comment: *abstraction* is the key to writing testable code - separate your concerns then write actual **unit** tests. SOLID is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible without additional effort from you.

Computer simply have no way to tell which computation affect what.

You can turn off specific features like printing to console by replacing default `PrintWriter`, but there is no generic solution.

Comment: hi talex, thanks so much for your answer. the helloworld program is just a example of course. I was thinking if there is anything like a generic switch for the whole program so I can toggle between testing mode and normal development mode.

Comment: @EugeneH you can take inspiration from what logging frameworks do. You set a logging level and when you call the logging method you specify at which level it should and should not log. I highly doubt that spraying your code with `if`s is an elegant and maintainable solution

Comment: @EugeneH no there is no such switch because it is theoretically impossible to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

**For your specific case** : you could use [PowerMock in order to mock `System.out`](http://ihaztehcodez.michael-lloyd-lee.me.uk/2009/10/mocking-system-classes.html), but the be honest I ignore the whole side effects it might have.

---

**More generally** : what you are looking for is called [Mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), and basically allows an instance of an `Object` to do nothing be the just minimum to run through your code.

For your case, mocking `System.out` would allow you to run through the calls to `System.out.println()` without actually calling those.
So as a result, your code would execute as if it was :

```
public class Helloworld {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static int greetingCnt = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Helloworld helloword = new Helloworld();
    helloword.greetWorld();
    helloword.greetWorld();
    helloword.greetWorld();
    // System.out.println("Greating count: " + greetingCnt);
}

public void greetWorld() {
    // System.out.println("Hello World!");
    ++greetingCnt;
    //some other computation...
}
```

I could go further in explaining how it *really* occurs, but I guess this is enough for your answer. If you are curious, you could look at runtime execution of your tests to inspect the real type of your mocked objects.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to make your Java program configurable.

One way to do this is using Java [property files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010833/creating-a-properties-file-in-java-and-eclipse). You can then use specific properties to disable parts of your program.

During testing you can then use one property file, and during normal execution another.

The property file is typically a resource on the Java class path. Then you can run the tests with a classpath containing the  property files describing the test configuration.

Comment: hi @avandeursen thanks so much for the answer. So from what I understand, the property files is like loading configurations, however, after getting the configurations, how can I implement the separation of testing and dev code? Shall I use if statement or switch/case statement? Or there is another more systematic way of doing it? Really appreciate your help :)